# Can't add "Space before paragraph" at the first paragraph on the second page in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I am using MS Word 2016 version. I can't add "Space before paragraph" on the first paragraph of the second page. But if I press "Enter" before the paragraph, then I can add "Space before paragraph" but in that case, the space amount will not be exactly same (eg: 12pt) as there is one manual spacing from the "Enter" at the beginning.

But surprisingly I can add "Space before paragraph" at the first paragraph on the first page without any problem (without giving any "Enter" at the beginning).

What is the solution for this problem? Please note that the "Suppress extra line spacing at top of page" is not checked from the Options>Advanced>Layout.

Here is the problematic MS word file for your reference:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/lzjh42ljkumdii0c5ezbq/before-spacing.docx?dl=0&rlkey=c5fd9amzwddde02anmz6xzkw6

The screenshot of my page with options:
[image]

Comment: How did you "end" the text on the first page? Did you use a page break?

Comment: Yes, I have added a Page Break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can put a Frame into the style that you want to have that spacing.

*Some time ago, Microsoft changed Word so that the space-before is ignored at the beginning of any page except the first page in a section. This is true no matter how the page is begun, except with a Section break. It is not advisable to use a Section break just to handle this spacing.* When a Frame is used, the Frame starts at the top of the page but the space before takes place inside the Frame. Frames can be invisible.

Here is my page with directions on how to [create a Frame as part of a style](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#CreatingFrames).

> **Using Frames to Provide Space Before a Heading after a Page Break**
> **(Column Break)**
>
> ```
> In recent versions of Word, Frames are required to provide space before the heading starting a new chapter after a page break or a
> ```
>
> column break. (Note: this is a problem with a page break or a column
> break, but not a page break inserted as part of a Section break.)
>
> ```
> By design, Word ignores the space setting for the paragraph without the Frame. The same thing happens with a column break. Word
> ```
>
> ignores the Space-before formatting of a paragraph style (or just
> paragraph formatting) when the paragraph is the first one on a page
> following a page break (or at the top of a column following a column
> break). You can use a Frame to get around this. The simplest method is
> to modify the Style:
> [image: screenshot of dialog box]
> You would want a borderless frame and to have the space-before paragraph formatting that you need.
>
> [image: screenshot of dialog box]

*Excerpt from my page on [Frames and Textboxes in Microsoft Word](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#StartPage)*

By the way, *your sample had no space-before set*. Here is [your documen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7nrbs5ggfrklg4/deleteme%20before%20spacing.docx?dl=0)t back with Heading 1 style being used and a Frame. Here is a [temporary link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7nrbs5ggfrklg4/deleteme%20before%20spacing.docx?dl=0) and screenshot. *The Frame shows up when text within it is selected. It does not print and does not appear when you are working outside the Frame.*

[image: Screenshot from repaired document]

You can add Page-Break-Before paragraph formatting to the style, also, if you want. This eliminates the need for the manual page break and makes editing easier. Applying the (heading) style automatically starts a new page.

Here is my writing on the [importance of Styles in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview). Here is Shauna Kelly's page on how [using the built-in heading styles can make things easier](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/usebuiltinheadingstyles.html).

**This answer applies to all versions of Word**, although using Frames for this purpose is not necessary in the menu versions (Word 2003 and earlier).

Comment: You are welcome. Once you've done it a couple of times it becomes very easy. You can also save the styles with the Frames as part of a Style Set. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#quick_style_set

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible without a workaround. There used to be a compatibility option `Suppress Space Before after a hard page or column break` which you could turn off. This is not the case any more in version 2013 and up.

There are several workarounds though, depending on the the type of text at the beginning of the page. E.g. if it's a heading you could use this solution: [How to add space before a heading in Word 2013 and 2016](http://www.lindipendente.eu/wp/en/2015/11/27/come-aggiungere-spazio-prima-di-unintestazione-in-word-2013-e-2016/), but if you do a search you can find several other ones as well.

"Easiest" Workaround would be to add the space manually. Since the problem will only occure after a page break there shouldn't be any complications with the manual space addition.

Comment: I have added the real file link in order to download and check the options which you are referencing. Please download and examine the file options and let me know. Thanks

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid Sorry, I don't download MS office files from external sources. But I was able to replicate the problem with the current version. So there's no need to download the file.

Comment: but I did not put checkmark on "Suppress Space Before after a hard page or column break" from the Options>Advanced in MS Word.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid do you have that option? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Please see my updated Question.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid It's as I said, you don't have the option (it has been removed in Word 2013 and up) thus you can not deactivate it. You will have to use one of the work around.

Comment: what are the work arounds??

Comment: I linked one possible workarounds, you can find several others on the web, if it doesn't suit your requirements. Easies Workaround would be to add the space manually. Since the problem will only occures after a page break there shouldn't be any complications.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier workaround: don’t update any Word-2011.docx you already have to Word-2013/2019.docx but just keep working in ‘Compatibility Mode’.

If you need to create a new document, save it asap as a .doc then use ‘Save As’ to convert it to a .docx but take care to keep the ‘Maintain compatibility with previous versions of Word’ box (underneath the ‘File Format’ dropdown-menu) ticked because it becomes a Word-2011.docx then, with all the wider/better possibilities Word 2011 offered.

As a former Word-mediator once counselled on his personal website: “Don’t upgrade to Word 2013, keep using Word 2011 until the wheels fall off and then use it some more.” Well, I guess with this workaround we’ve arrived at the ‘use it some more’ stadium.